# Unparseable date exception when converting a string to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Tags: java, sql, parsing, datetime, sybase

Hi I am trying to convert a string 19611015 to a date formate of ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") before storing it into a sybase database table. I have tried the below code which gives me the error:

Unparseable date: "19611015"

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(formatter.parse("19611015"));
```

I have been reading some long and complex solutions to this, some suggesting to use Locale. Could someone explain maybe an alternative simple solution to convert string I have to a date format I am after above. Thank you.

Comment: `19611015` is not in the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: 19611015 is in which format ??

Comment: you should use yyyyMMdd instead of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: I tried yyyyMMdd but still no luck. I want this to look like 
1961-10-15 00:00:00

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `date` in string is in yyyyMMdd format and want to convert it into yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss so use below code :

```
        DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = originalFormat.parse("19611015");
        String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date); 
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Output :

```
1961-10-15 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Achilles, below code might solve your problem:

```
package com.test;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class LongToDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(19611015 * 1000);
        String dateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatString);
        String result = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(result);
        //Output: 1969-12-10 15:46:18
    }
}
```

Comment: 19611015 became 1969-12-10 15:46:18?

Comment: Hello ZouZou, I am converting long value to MS and then parsing. Please let me know if this is incorrect.

Comment: IMHO, `19611015` means `1961-10-15`. And `19611015 * 1000` overflows.

Comment: Opps, I thought 19611015 is MilliSecond, my bad.

Comment: Even if it was, your code won't work since `19611015 * 1000` overflows.